# Please explain how this prime number generator code works (in C)

Tags: c, for-loop, primes

```
int prime (int poss_prime);  

int main() {  

    int poss_prime;  

    for (poss_prime = 2; poss_prime <= MAX_INT; poss_prime++) {  
        if (prime (poss_prime)) {  
            printf("%d ", poss_prime);  
        }  
    }  

    printf("\n\n");  
    return 0;  
}  

int prime (int poss_prime) {  

    int poss_factor;  

    for (poss_factor = 2; poss_factor <= poss_prime/2; poss_factor++) {  
        if (poss_prime % poss_factor == 0) {  
            return 0;  
        }  
    }  

    return 1;

}
```

I don't understand why the function can be used as the condition in the if statement, and why poss_prime is divided by two in the for loop condition. Thank you.

Comment: The division by two either means the implementer didn't really understand what they were up to, or they thought that `sqrt` costs an awful lot.

Comment: @dmckee not only that, but also that `sqrt(n)` is of worse complexity than O(sqrt(n)). Even with this implementation: `sqrt(int n){int c=1;while(c*c<=n)++c;return c-1;}`, the `sqrt`-using version wins over the halving one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the function `prime()` has as its return type an integer. Putting the function call in the if statement is equivalent to

```
int value = prime(possprime);
if(value)
```

It is just a neater way of doing so, if you do not subsequently require that return value.
logical expressions in C also accept numerical arguments. 0 is false, and any positive integer is true. I don't know the result of a negative integer.

it would be clearer, however, if you used bool as the return type of prime, to make it clear it is a true/false situation.

As for the prime generator itself: It is checking for all factors of that number. It cannot have any factors greater than half the original value (excluding itself), which is why the for loop only goes to half of the possible primes value.

Comment: Then if the value has any factors, the function returns 0, or false, indicating it is not a prime.

Comment: Negative numbers are also truthy in C-like languages.

Comment: So if it returns 0 (False), then it prints the numbers?? That doesn't make sense to me for some reason..

Comment: No, If it returns 0, false, then it does not reach the next line, and does not print the number. If it returns 1, true, then it does reach the next line, and print the number. The statement says, in english, "If this number is a prime, print the number to the screen"

Answer (score 0):

Basic programming.

The function `prime` returns 1 or 0, depending on what it finds.  In C, 0 means "false" and 1 means "true".

Re the divide by 2, if there is any factor of the number, it must be half the number or less, since the smallest possible factor is 2.